# cant get socket.io to poll (node,js, express, ejs, socket.io)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Im trying to get socket.io work.
    This are the packages I use:

```
"express": "~4.9.0",
"ejs": "~0.8.5",
"socket.io":"~1.3.3"
```

my app.js:

```
// loading modules
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

//routers
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

// Setup serving static assets
app.use(express.static('public'));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
   console.log(data);
  });
});


// Setup initial routing - index
app.use('/', indexRouter);


// Start the server
server.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log('App listening at http://localhost:3000');
});
```

my router:

```
var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("index");
});

module.exports = router;
```

my template

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Real time web chat</title>
    <script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
</head>
 <body>
  hi world!
 </body>
</html>
```

Now I keep getting :

> GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1452340948465-61 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Im not sure what im doing wrong. As far as I understand I attached socket.io to the server the right ways?

Hope anyone can point out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your node server listens on port 3000. Change this on client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
```

to

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

Also check the socket.io tutorial: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

EDIT:

I recreated your code at my server. If client side code is like yours:

```
<script>
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
            socket.on('news', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
            });
        </script>
```

in console i got "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

When I change client side code

```
<script>
                var socket = io();
                socket.on('news', function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
                });
            </script>
```

everything works fine. It seems that the problem is in initialization of client socket variable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it stills gives the same error. I used that tutorials as reference earlier but it cant find what they do what I didnt in my code.

Comment: @Merijn in your client side code, try to initialize socket.io without URL:  var socket=io().  According to manual it will try connect to the host that serves the page.